# How to persist the data in a single Global temp table called multiple times in a single session- db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, temp-tables

Team, consider i have a Stored procedure have declared global temp table and inserting single row in to it and will return back to java and again i ll call same SP and insert another row.

Finally i will call another SP and i will fetch the rows from global temp table.

but issue is am getting only the last row from the temp table.Meaning: its replacing.

Stored Procedure:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE T_LOAD(
.
.
.
)NOT LOGGED WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

 Insert into T_LOAD(...)values(...);
```

Please suggest a way to proceed.

Comment: "_Meaning: its replacing._" Do you think this may have something to do with the option you use, `WITH REPLACE`?

Comment: If i remove With replace . then its throwing error

Comment: What is throwing an error? When is it thrown? What error is thrown?